# Почему выводятся дети только первого родителя

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Есть исходный массив объектов `data_properties`. В каждом объекте три поля:

- `id_properties` - уникальный id
- `name_properties` - название
- `num_properties` - родитель (0 по умолчанию)

Пример:

```
data_properties: [ 
    { 'id_properties':'1', 'name_properties':'parent1', 'num_properties':'0' },
    { 'id_properties':'2', 'name_properties':'parent2', 'num_properties':'0' },
    { 'id_properties':'3', 'name_properties':'test1', 'num_properties':'1' },
    { 'id_properties':'4', 'name_properties':'test2', 'num_properties':'3' },
    { 'id_properties':'5', 'name_properties':'test3', 'num_properties':'2' } 
]
```

Мне нужно вывести все опции, но только по порядку вложенности (родитель-ребёнок). В данном случае:

```
parent1,test1,test2,parent2,test3
```

Делаю так, но не выводятся другие родительские элементы:

```
function get_val(num) {
    for (i = 0; i < data_properties.length; i++) {
        if (data_properties[i]["num_properties"] == num) {
            alert(data_properties[i]['name_properties']);
            get_val(data_properties[i]["id_properties"]);
        }
    }
}

get_val(0);
```

Comment: потому что забыл var перед `i` в цикле

Comment: спасибо . Помогли :)